# Jenkins DSL - Pipeline Job (Unexpected token '$')

Tags: jenkins, job-dsl

I have the following DSL code and I´m getting error on line 13, `$class`. I guess than everything inside `script("""...""")` is parsed as plain text to the pipeline definition but I don´t know what´s wrong or how to escape the `$` character.

My code:

```
pipelineJob('DSL-Test') {

parameters {
    choiceParam ('version', ['1.2.1', '1.2.0'], 'Docker Version')
}

definition {
    cps {
        sandbox(boolean sandbox = true)
        script("""
            node ('master'){
                stage('Git Checkout'){
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'mycrednetial', url: 'myurl']]])
                }
            }
        """.stripIndent()) 
         }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Processing provided DSL script ERROR: startup failed: script: 13:
>   unexpected token: class @ line 13, column 24.
>                             checkout([$class: 'GitSCM'])
>                             ^
>
> 1 error
>
> Started calculate disk usage of build Finished Calculation of disk
>   usage of build in 0 seconds Started calculate disk usage of workspace
>   Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds Finished:
>   FAILURE

Does anyone know how to make that character not display error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just managed how to escape characters.

The solution is to add: "\" before the character.

```
checkout([\$class:....
```

Comment: Could you mark this answer as resolved if this solved the issue?

Comment: I tried you suggestion for the following case: `wrap([$class: 'BuildUser'])` but got `nexpected char : '\'`